# Redux state has changed, why doesn't it trigger a re-render? (Redux-saga)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-saga

I'm using react + redux + redux saga

I'm facing the issue that when I'm rendering the page (GET call)
The calls should be like:

1. constructor
2. render()
3. componentDidMount
4. render()

But I'm just reaching up to `componentDidMount`, `mapDispatchToProps` is dispatching the action, API call is working by which getting the response from the server and the data is updated into the state.
**BUT** somewhere it gets lost and my component is not even re rendering.
Up to the reducer, I'm getting the data where I'm returning `action.items`.

#### itemReducer.js

```
const itemReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.GET_ALL_ITEMS_SUCCESS:
      console.log("itemReducer-----", action.items); //getting the data over here
      return action.items;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

#### itemPage.js (component)

```
class ItemsPage extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadItems();
      }

     render() {
        const { items } = this.props; // not even it renders, so not getting data
        ...
        return (<div>...</div>);
     }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.items,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadItems: () => dispatch(loadAllItemsAction()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemsPage);
```

Please give some suggestions, *Thanks in advance* :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't issue in the code that you posted. To make sure I pretty much copy pasted the code you shared, filled in the missing parts and it works just fine:
https://codesandbox.io/s/3tuxv?file=/src/index.js

My guess what might be wrong is that your items are not stored in `state.items` but under some different path or you might be missing the react-redux Provider, but it is impossible to say for sure without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Thanks @martin-kadlec, your snippet helped me to find that missing part i.e. `items: itemReducer` where I was missing the key `items`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand that the calls of render/componentDidMount are not so linear as it could be expected. componentDidMount fires when all children were **mount**. And it doesn't means that render() was finished already.

Read here for more info:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2659